# Can not see Pycharm Monokai highlight color

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I like the Monokai theme that **Pycharm 2017.3** comes with, but I can't see what I'm highlighting.

E.g.:

Nothing highlighted:

[image: lines 7-9 without highlight]

Highlighted the word **`delete_table`**:

[image: Highlighted the variable delete_table]

**Question:** How do I change the highlight color in PyCharm?

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

In *Settings* (`Ctrl+Alt+S`) > *Editor* > *Color* *Scheme* > *General*,

under *Editor* > *Selection background*:

[image]

Increased color brighness to `60`, now I can see!

[image: Aha moment!]